# Need opinion with relations count

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

Very long time I searching for solution for this problem:

Lets say we have 2 tables one table is Clients table and second table is ClientAssignment table:
the ClientAssignment table is related to Clients table:

```
public function assignment()
{
    return $this->hasOne(ClientAssignment::class, 'client_id');
}
```

now when I want to count how many ClientAssignment has Clients and i do it like that:

```
$users =[1,2,3,4 .....]
$userAssignments = array();

foreach ($users as $user) {

    $user_assignments = Client::whereHas('assignment', function ($query) use ($user) {
     $query->where('assigned_id', $user);
    });

     $ua['user_id'] = $user;
     $ua['count'] = $user_assignments->count();
     array_push($userAssignments, $ua);
   }
```

The code works well but it hits the performance and query execution time ~20 + seconds on a relatively small table with 80k Clients,
My question if can be another way to do the same thing but with minimum performance and query execution time hit ?

Comment: First thing, 
```
public function assignment()
{
    return $this->hasOne(ClientAssignment::class, 'client_id');
}
```
this should probale be 
```
public function assignment()
{
    return $this->hasMany(ClientAssignment::class, 'client_id');
}
```,

Comment: No, this is not a good way. I am not sure in your relationship. but I prefer raw query like 
DB::table('assignment')->groupBy('user_id')->wereIn('user_id', [...])->where('client_id', 1)->count('id')  
something

Comment: Second thing, you don't have to use eloquent, you can run a row sql, 
like 
```
SELECT *, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `assignment` WHERE `assignment`.`client_id` = `clients`.`id) as assignmentCount FROM `clients`
```

Comment: Just use one query to solve this.

Comment: And what about the `assigned_id`, `user` has many `client_assignments`, `client` has one `client_assignment`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your post, I think

```
Client --- hasOne ----> ClientAssignment  <----- hasMany ---- User
                    [client_id, assigned_id]
```

So `User` can hasMany `Client` through `ClientAssignment`,

However, your `client_id` and `assigned_id` are all in `client_assignment` table. So you can not use `hasManyThrough`, this just like a pivot table;

Fortunately, you can directly count the `client_id` and get the `assigned_id` as `user_id` just use this pivot table.

The query is like this (Use `distinct(client_id)` for preventing the dirty records):

```php
ClientAssignment::whereIn('assigned_id', $users)
                  ->groupBy('assigned_id')
                  ->select('assigned_id AS user_id',
                            DB::raw('COUNT(DISTINCT(client_id)) AS count'))
                  ->get()->toArray();
```

And add `assigned_id` index to improve the performance.

```php
$table->index('assigned_id');
```

Comment: Thanks , this is very useful it helped me in other places and tested it, but sorry if I not mentioned before but we have query filtering "chaining"  with the Client class like: $this->applyFiltering($user_assignments, $request);   and in the applyFiltering function has at least 50 filters / query builders that related to Client class           
 so it need to be the Client class  and not ClientAssignment

Comment: for example the 'ended' col is refered to Clients table/class;     if ($request->has('ended')) {   $user_assignments->where('ended', 1); }

Answer (score 0):

Use the `count()`

```php
Client::first()->assignments->count();

// Or

Client::find(ID)->assignments()->count();

// or ...
```